# get values between two datetimes, but only considering hours

Tags: sqlite, datetime

I have a sqlite database that contains Date column which containt dates every 15 minutes

```
 Date                   Hourly_value   quart_value

"2015-12-30 03:00:00"   "944.691025"  "987.196765"

"2015-12-30 03:15:00"   "941.060427"

"2015-12-30 03:30:00"   "967.305421"    

"2015-12-30 03:45:00"   "987.196765"    

"2015-12-30 04:00:00"   "1016.272784"   "1017.077076"
```

I want to get hourly_values only between 2 dates, so when i want to get the values between "2015-12-30 03:00:00" and "2015-12-30 04:00:00", i want to get

```
Date                   Hourly_value   quart_value

"2015-12-30 03:00:00"   "944.691025"  "987.196765"
"2015-12-30 04:00:00"   "1016.272784"   "1017.077076"
```

and not values every 15 minutes

```
 Date                   Hourly_value   quart_value

 "2015-12-30 03:00:00"   "944.691025"  "987.196765"

 "2015-12-30 03:15:00"   "941.060427"

 "2015-12-30 03:30:00"   "967.305421"    

 "2015-12-30 03:45:00"   "987.196765"    

 "2015-12-30 04:00:00"   "1016.272784"   "1017.077076"
```

In sql i can't find a way to get the dates between a certain range considering only hours, because using between will give me 4 values (1 value every 15 minutes ).

```
SELECT * FROM Conso WHERE Date BETWEEN '2015-12-30 03:00:00' AND '2015-12-30 
04:00:00'
```

Comment: I can see that quart_value is null in between hours rows. If this is the case, you could filter columns on the condition quart_value is not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more general solution could be    `SELECT* From Conso WHERE (Date BETWEEN '2015-12-30 03:00:00' AND '2015-12-30 ) AND (INSTR(Date,':00:00') >0)`

Comment: thanks for your answer, instr didn't work for me because i have an old version of sqlite and needed to upgrade, but you gave me an idea and i used LIKE %Date% and it worked also.